# You Tube - Disable all links to actual video in the player

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, lightbox

I am using a light box type of player to open and play you tube videos. My people don't want the video link to be accessible or shared from within the player.

I.E they only want the video to play when the video loads in the player. So they don't want the share button visible and they don't want the YouTube icon that links directly to the video visible.

I can remove the share button and I can remove the YouTube icon but not at the same time.So there is always an easy way for the user to get the video url and share it etc...

I can also chose the videos to be private and that removes both. But then all of my users would need a google account which they dont.

It seems to me that Google wouldn't offer free use to its player without some type of reference to You Tube. Either with the share button or the You Tube icon that links to the video.

i have tried modifying the url parameters (embed?v=#v_ID#&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent&modestbranding=1&controls=0") to no avail.

And I have tried using embed and watch to no avail..

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hi Patrick, are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can append the following onto the end of the YouTube embed url, to remove the `Watch on YouTube` button from the playback controls which is accomplished by setting [`modestbranding`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding) to 1. The player controls are NOT removed. they are just auto0hidden by setting the parameter `autohide` to 1.

Try to change `&` to `&amp`

Here's a sample format to solves your issue: